# how to get click event in itemTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a gridView.
ıt has an Itemptemplate (textblock, image) and itemsource. textBlock and Image are binded to itemsource.
I want to add a button to ItempTemplate but I couldn't able to detect the eventHandler.
In my .cs file I dont see textblock, image or button.
how can I set the event,

here is the code of item template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IDViewStyle">
        <Grid Width="350" Height="450" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Border Background="#B2060606" />
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="eraseButton" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Image Source="/Assets/Images/erease.png" Width="90" Margin="0,-7,-15,15"/>
                </Button>
                <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="+" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" FontSize="160" Margin="0"/>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Ekle" TextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Image  Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            </Grid>

            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Type}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and my .cs file

```
Data.IdentityTypeCollection collection;
gView.SelectionChanged += lvIdTypes_SelectionChanged;
collection = new Data.IdentityTypeCollection();
gView.ItemsSource = collection;
gView.ScrollIntoView(collection);
```

and my mainpage.xaml

`<GridView x:Name="gView" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="117,0,0,100"   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IDViewStyle}"/>`

how can I use button event in the item template

Comment: posting the code would help

Comment: You'll likely need to bind the button to a command on a view-model. Like @makc said, code would make it easier to figure out how to help.

Comment: I^ve posted the the codes

Comment: did you try to add click event Click="btn_Click"?

Comment: You can set the event in the xaml by adding `Click="YourEventNameHere"`. This click event will be **common** to all of your GridView items.

Comment: its not working.
I added click event to dataTemplate but its not seen in the cs file
also I used a different way that I dont use cs file under the xaml due to custom framework I use I created a class file and sets the xaml to that cs file. I also had to set all the ui elements in the cs file as well

Answer (score 0):

On GridView you can assign a property `ItemClick="YourClickEvent"` like:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"></GridView>
```

and in your .cs file the event handler:

```
 void YourClickEvent(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
 {
    //your codes here
 }
```

Make sure GridView `IsItemClickEnabled` is set to `True` All set!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then this is what I did after using the debugger to look around. This is a UWP application. The Button is in a Grid in a DataTemplate in a "MedView" GridView. The following sets the ItemsSource:

```
List<ViewItemClass> lvil = new List<ViewItemClass>();
// create lvil
MedView.ItemsSource = lvil;
```

Then I added a Click event handler for the **Button** and the following is the code for that:

```
Button b = sender as Button;
if (b == null)
    return;
Grid g = b.Parent as Grid;
if (g == null)
    return;
ViewItemClass lvi = g.DataContext as ViewItemClass;
if (lvi == null)
    return;
// use the item
```